How to create a countdown timer in an email?
I want to create a countdown timer, which will show how much time is left before the event.
I know that this cannot be done with AMPscript or SSJS. AMP for emails is also out. Is it somehow possible to build this in CloudPage or otherwise and put it in an email?
I know of products such as https://www.motionmailapp.com/, just looking for other options.

It is not possible to build a countdown timer, without utilising a 3rd party application. Features within SFMC would not be able provide you with the ability to display such a timer.
Litmus has a good article about these timers: https://www.litmus.com/blog/using-countdown-timers-to-boost-engagement
